# Microsoft Access 2010 open all files in a directory

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating an MS Access 2010 database.   I am using the API to do what the common dialog control did in previous versions of MS Access to open a directory and select a file.  My client would like me to be able to open all of the files in the directory when a user clicks on a folder (so the user does not click on a file, just a folder).   I cannot find an even triggering when the folder is clicked on within the common dialog control that comes up using the API.

Can anyone tell me how to open all the files in a directory (they will be .pdf files) when using the API for the common dialog control in MS ACCESS 2010?

The API calls I am using are here:  http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use a FileSystemObject from Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime (must add reference to the project).
The following sub adds to a collection the string names of all pdf files in a given folder.
Get the folder path from the dialog (with folder picking option, not file picking)

```
Sub GetFolderPDFFiles(FolderPath As String, Col As Collection)

    Dim FS As New FileSystemObject
    Dim Dir As Folder
    Dim Arq As File

    Set Dir = FS.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    For Each Arq In Dir.Files
        If UCase(Right(Arq.Name, 4)) = ".PDF" Then
            Call Col.Add(Arq.Path)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me... it will promt the dialog box to select the folder and open the .pdf files. it will also list all the files in Table1.

```
    Option Compare Database
```

> 'function to select the folder where the files are:

```
    Function ChooseFolder() As String


        Dim fldr As FileDialog
        Dim sItem As String

        Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fldr
            .Title = "Select a Folder"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = strPath
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

    NextCode:
        ChooseFolder = sItem
        Set fldr = Nothing

    End Function
```

> Enter the routines to open and list the pdf files in the folder (it also look for files in subfolders):

```
    Sub Open_List_Files()


    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder, objTopFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim strTopFolderName As String, ProjectF As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' call the function to select the folder
    Call Módulo1.ChooseFolder

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    'Get the top folder
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)

    'Call the RecursiveFolder routine
    Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)


End Sub

Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Scripting.Folder, IncludeSubFolders As Boolean)

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim DBStr, filepath As String

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    On Error Resume Next

    If InStr(objFile.Name, ".pdf") Then

    DBStr = "INSERT INTO Table1 ([File Name]) " & _
            " VALUES (" & _
            "'" & objFile.Name & "', " & "');"

    CurrentDb.Execute DBStr

    'open the file
    Application.FollowHyperlink objFile

    End If

    Next objFile

    'Loop through files in the subfolders
    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If


End Sub
```

Run the Open_List_Files() Macro and there you go! :)